# Problem with Scala Function and Call-by-Name

Tags: scala, callbyname

I am trying to loop a the second parameter (exp) in this function that uses call by name parameters. The first 3 parameters are the index, boolean to stop loop, and increment function. I am getting an output with 10 '()'s when I am trying to loop "hello world" 10 times as seen in the test code. May I get some help with what is wrong here? Thanks

```
def forLoop(ival: => Int, f: (Int) => Boolean, g: (Int)=>Int)(exp: => Unit): Unit = {
  if(f(ival)==false) 
    return
  else {
    println(exp)
    forLoop(g(ival),f,g)(exp)
  }
}

def f(x: Int): Boolean = { x<10 }
def g(y: Int): Int = { y+1 }
val exp: Unit = "Hello World"
forLoop(0,f,g)("Hello World")
```

Comment: Also I think I formatted the parameter functions f and g when trying to use call by name but I am not sure.

Comment: I have changed it to return Unit and changed return true to just return in the base case. My bad. Sorry I am new

Comment: ok i have updated

Answer (score 2):

The value `"Hello World"` is of type `String` however you are assigning it to `Unit`

```
val exp: Unit = "Hello World"
```

which compiler expands to

```
val exp: Unit = {
  "Hello World";
  ()
}
```

Note how `()` becomes the value of `exp`. Try changing the definition of `exp` to

```
val exp: String = "Hello World"
```

and second parameter list to

```
(exp: => String)
```

If you compile with compiler flag `-Wvalue-discard`, for example,

```
scala -Wvalue-discard -e 'val exp: Unit = "Hello World"'
```

you will get a warning

```
warning: discarded non-Unit value
val exp: Unit = "Hello World"
                ^
```

Comment: I get the same result even when I declare val exp: String = "Hello World"

Comment: Oh, my I am required to have the second parameter as Unit

Answer (score 2):

I think this meets your requirements.

```
def forLoop(ival: => Int, f: =>Int => Boolean, g: =>Int=>Int
           )(exp: => Unit): Unit =
  if (f(ival)) {
    exp
    forLoop(g(ival),f,g)(exp)
  }

def f(x: Int): Boolean = x<10
def g(y: Int): Int = y+1
def exp: Unit = println("Hello World")
forLoop(0,f,g)(exp)
```